# INSERT ... IGNORE from another table

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-select

I want to insert some records that comes from a table into another table using `INSERT ... IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE into separa (no_cliente,contratante) values (select cl_num,cl_aseg from clientes)
```

But MySQL tells that I'm wrong, any help?

Answer (score 5):

Remove `VALUES` and braces, exclude `SELECT`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO separa (no_cliente, contratante)
SELECT cl_num, cl_aseg FROM clientes;
```

Read more [*here*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).